# How to create 2 different scripts for 2 browsers (IE+all the rest)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'm trying to solve an IE CSS issue by using conditional tags. My jQuery that does the job of tabbed box effect calls an id that is inside the conditional tags. I've given new ids to IE so on IE the jQuery is not working. I tried to duplicate the script with the new id in one of the script but the 2 scripts seems to get in conflict.

My jQuery (in between the head tags) is (for all all browsers except IE):

```
  <script>
var currentTab = 0; // Set to a different number to start on a different tab.

function openTab(clickedTab) {
 var thisTab = $(".tabbed-box .tabs a").index(clickedTab);
 $(".tabbed-box .tabs li a").removeClass("active");
 $(".tabbed-box .tabs li a:eq("+thisTab+")").addClass("active");
 $(".tabbed-box .tabbed-content").hide();
 $(".tabbed-box .tabbed-content:eq("+thisTab+")").show();
 currentTab = thisTab;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".tabs li:eq(0) a").css("border-left", "none");

 $(".tabbed-box .tabs li a").click(function() { 
  openTab($(this)); return false; 
 });

 $(".tabbed-box .tabs li a:eq("+currentTab+")").click()
});
</script>
```

And I would need this for IE:

```
    <script>
var currentTab = 0; // Set to a different number to start on a different tab.

function openTab(clickedTab) {
 var thisTab = $(".tabbed-box .tabs a").index(clickedTab);
 $(".tabbed-box ie-.tabs li a").removeClass("active");
 $(".tabbed-box ie-.tabs li a:eq("+thisTab+")").addClass("active");
 $(".tabbed-box .tabbed-content").hide();
 $(".tabbed-box .tabbed-content:eq("+thisTab+")").show();
 currentTab = thisTab;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".ie-tabs li:eq(0) a").css("border-left", "none");

 $(".tabbed-box .ie-tabs li a").click(function() { 
  openTab($(this)); return false; 
 });

 $(".tabbed-box .ie-tabs li a:eq("+currentTab+")").click()
});
</script>
```

Having the 2 scripts in the head conflicts with each other. Maybe there is a way to combine them?

Comment: Is the difference between both the scripts only the class names `tabs` and `ie-tabs`?

Comment: would it not be possible to write differing CSS (or use other hacks) to handle the IE specific nature, such that you can keep the same CSS class names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IE Conditional comments** are your friend

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script>
   // The IE script
</script>
<![endif]-->

<![if !IE]>
<script>
   // The script for other browsers
</script>
<![endif]>
```

IE will only see the first script. All other browers see only the second one.

If you only wish to have this "special treatment" for a certain **old version of IE**, but newer ones like IE8 or IE9 behave properly and can use the standard script, then write the condition like this:

```
<!--[if IE lte 6]>
   // The script for IE6 and below
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

This way only IE 6 and below will see this script. Newer IE versions will use the standard script.

This also allows you to **cleanly throw away** the special script, once support for these versions of IE is no longer required.

Comment: These should only really be used in exceptional cases, like if IE access some hideous activeX API. Or if your still working with IE6, recent versions of IE behave nicely enough to have no need for this.

Comment: True. The questions however indirectly refers to workarounds for IE, which probably indicates that support for an older version is required. I've expanded my answer to make this clearer.

Comment: Even though you can use IE conditional checks, they are only good for quick hack-ish fixes. In almost all cases you can rewrite the code via an alternative method or to include proper feature detection. I meant to say IE conditionals should be last line of defence against browser compatibility issues. Although IE conditional checks are still useful for CSS.

Comment: Why should they only be used for "quick hack-ish fixes"? I see them as a perfectly fine way to cleanly isolate all IE 6 or 7 css & js workarounds. This way you don't need to litter your code with checks and you can cleanly throw them away once support for these browser versions is no longer required.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid browser detection and instead work on feature detection. In this case the feature your looking for is whether there is an object with the `.ie-tabs` class

The easiest thing to do is

```
var tabs;
if ($(".ie-tabs").length > 0) {
    tabs = $(".ie-tabs");
} else {
    tabs = $(".tabs");
}
```

then change to code to reference everything else using $.fn.find

```
tabs.find("li a").removeClass("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to figure out whether the browser supports certain features.

From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/

Rather than using $.browser to detect the current user agent and alter the page presentation based on which browser is running, it is a good practice to perform feature detection. This means that prior to executing code which relies on a browser feature, we test to ensure that the feature works properly. To make this process simpler, jQuery performs many such tests and makes the results available to us as properties of the jQuery.support object.

Following are a few resources that explain how feature detection works:

- http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/feature-detection-state-of-the-art-browser-scripting
- http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/not_browser_detect.html
- http://yura.thinkweb2.com/cft/

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to determine the browser and script to use, like so:

```
$(function () {
    if ($.browser.msie) {
        /** IE version here... **/
    }
    else {
        /** Other version here... **/
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work for me. I'm sure I just left some unnecessary }: or ) in the ie or ff code.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass multiple CSS selectors to the $() function if you separate them by a comma. For example:

```
$(".tabbed-box .tabs li a, .tabbed-box .ie-tabs li a").click(function() { 
  openTab($(this)); return false; 
});
```

That's the combined version. You can use the same concept for all of the rest of the calls to $().

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to check if ie

if ( $.browser.msie ) {

alert( "this is ie version " + $.browser.version );

}